# Always append a per link routing domain with NetworkManager to be used by systemd-resolved

Tags: linux, networking, dns, systemd, networkmanager

I'm using a global DNS server with the routing domain `~.` to make sure that DNS queries are not being leaked:

```ini
# cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns.conf
[Resolve]
DNS=1.2.3.4#example.org
DNSOverTLS=yes
Domains=~.
```

Since I'm using NetworkManager and not systemd-networkd, I'm also using this configuration to disable DNS-over-TLS by default for all links:

```ini
# cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf
[connection]
connection.dns-over-tls=0
```

If per link search domains exist, DNS queries for that domain are resolved with the local DNS server, like they should:

```
# resolvectl
Global
         Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 1.2.3.4#example.org
       DNS Servers: 1.2.3.4#example.org
        DNS Domain: ~.

Link 3 (wlo1)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
        DNS Domain: local

# resolvectl query device.local
device.local: 192.168.1.2                  -- link: wlo1

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 31.6ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no; Data was acquired via local or encrypted transport: no
-- Data from: network
```

If I manually append a routing domain with `resolvectl domain wlo1 local ~detectportal.firefox.com`, it also works for the additional domain. What I'm trying to achieve is to automate this process, without losing the search domain that I received from the DHCP server. I want to do this for all WiFi connections, including ones that I've never connected to before. The reason is that I want to allow Firefox to detect portals using the local DNS server.

I haven't had any luck creating something like this, which should work with systemd-networkd, but seems to be ignored by systemd-resolved if systemd-networkd is not used:

```ini
# cat /etc/systemd/network/dns.conf
[Match]
Name=wlo1

[Network]
Domains=~detectportal.firefox.com
```

Not to mention that this would replace the search domain, instead of appending the routing domain.

Since I've posted this question I came up with my own [solution](https://superuser.com/a/1758957/1757830). Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

if [[ $1 != wl* || ! $2 =~ dhcp[46]-change ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

link="$(/usr/sbin/ip link show dev "$1")"
link="${link%%:*}"
domains=(detectportal.firefox.com true)
domains+=($(/usr/bin/busctl --json=short get-property org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager Domains | /usr/bin/jq --argjson link "$link" --raw-output '.data[] | select(.[0] == $link) | .[1], .[2]'))
/usr/bin/busctl call org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager SetLinkDomains 'ia(sb)' "$link" "$((${#domains[@]}/2))" "${domains[@]}"
```

This should be placed in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`.